# http redirect and append client IP as URL query

Tags: nginx, redirect, haproxy, querystring

i have this weird issue which we need as a workaoround for an internal application limitation.

this is what I need, either from haproxy or nginx:

- something calls `http://my-server/?some=query_string`
- the server should respond with a redirect (http 301/302) to this location: `http://my-other-server/?some=query_string?client_ip=ACTUAL_CLIENT_IP`

could somebody provide an idea about how this might work? or even better still - the DNS reverse lookup name for the client IP?

thanks in advance!
axel.

Comment: You want a second `?` in the query string? That's definitely not normal.

Comment: Doesn't your other server get the client IP after redirect anyway?

Comment: @MichaelHampton nope, that's a mistake, it should be a "&" of course.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen yup, but unfortunately that does not help - like i said it's a workaround for an internal app limitation. I just need to append &client_ip=THING (and again - even better if $THING would be the lookup of the dns *name* of the caller)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
location / {
    return 301 http://my-other-server/?client_ip=$remote_addr&$args;
}
```

This will assign the IP address. https://github.com/flant/nginx-http-rdns is a reverse DNS lookup module for nginx, which provides `$rdns_hostname` variable, which you can use instead of `$remote_addr`. However, you need to compile the module to your nginx to use it.

Comment: Note that doing a DNS lookup here will increase your TTFB by the time it takes to do the lookup. It may or may not be worth doing in real time. It can always be done later.